# Text find inside a cross-domain iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

Is it possible i can find and compare some text strings between my website and a cross domain iframe inside it? 
Suppose i have:

```
<html>
<body>
<div><p>hello world</p></div>
<iframe><html><body><div><p>hello world</p></div></body></html>
</body>
</html>
```

is it possible to build a find and compare algorithm that will be able to check the text on my website and compare it with the one inside the cross domain iframe? Should i require the use of the `postmessage` or is there something simpler in terms of just making just a simple text find and compare inside the browser screen?

Comment: postMessage is the only way

Comment: If you can write some code in the iframe, then you can fire an event when the iframe is loaded, and then on listening to the event from the parent html, you can check the values.

Comment: @Indra actually the iframe content are my twitter page and i want to compare some tweet text with my weebsite.

Comment: Ok, in that case, I think there is no other option.

Comment: @quentin can i use tokens?

Answer (score 1):

A Javascript function running in one frame will not be able to access DOM of other frame if the domains are different. Your need to have the same method loaded in both frame. One approach to do it can be that you load the find/compare JS function in both frames then call it in one frame. Once the key is found in the present frame then via `postMessage`, send the event to call the same function in the iframe. If in iframe also, you find the same key then you can do `postMessage` to parent frame that the key has been found.

However if the domains are same then you can access the DOM of an iframe via jQuery like:

```
var iframeElementContents = $("#yourIFrame").contents();
```

And now you can run your JS function on this element.